# Meklord Emperor Wisel vs Dragonic Diagram

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Meklord Emperor Wisel](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Meklord_Emperor_Wisel):

> Cannot be Normal Summoned/Set. Must be Special Summoned by its own
>   effect, and cannot be Special Summoned by other ways. When a face-up
>   monster you control is destroyed by a card effect and sent to the
>   Graveyard (except during the Damage Step): You can Special Summon this
>   card from your hand. Other monsters you control cannot declare an
>   attack. Once per turn: You can target 1 Synchro Monster your opponent
>   controls; equip that target to this card. This card gains ATK equal to
>   the combined ATK of the monsters equipped to it by this effect. Once
>   per turn, during either player's turn, when your opponent activates a
>   Spell Card: You can negate the activation, and if you do, destroy it.

[Dragonic Diagram](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonic_Diagram):

> All "True Draco" and "True King" monsters on the field gain 300
>   ATK/DEF. The first time each Tribute Summoned "True Draco" or "True
>   King" monster would be destroyed by battle each turn, it is not
>   destroyed. Once per turn: You can destroy 1 other card you control or
>   in your hand, and if you do, add 1 "True Draco" or "True King" card
>   from your Deck to your hand.

Player A has Dragonic Diagram is already on field. Then player B summons Meklord Emperor Wisel. Then player A wants to activate his Dragonic Diagram's effect. Can player B negate it with Meklord Emperor Wisel's effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you activated the effect of a Spell Card, not the card itself. All instances of activating a Spell Card *is* activating a Spell Card effect, but it is not the case that all instances of activating a Spell Card effect is activating a Spell Card.